# Google map resize not solving partial display issue within a modal dialogue

Tags: google-maps-api-3, simplemodal

I known this question has been raised and answered many times but I can't seem to make the suggested solutions work for me...
I'm displaying a google map within a simplemodal dialogue.
Outside the modal dialogue the map displays correctly.
However, once inside a modal wrapper only part of the map is shown on the first iteration (see below).
The solution would appear to involve binding a 'resize' event to the map but it isn't working for me...

First iteration:
On opening the modal for the first iteration, my map displays with the partial section displaced over to the top RHS and overlaid on the full map.
On closing the first dialogue the screen returns to it's initial state.

Second and subsequent iterations:
On subsequent iterations the map displays correctly but on closing the background color of the map canvas is visible.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button class="modalMap">With Modal </button>
    <button class="nonModalMap">Without Modal </button>
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#simplemodal-overlay    {background-color:#000;}
#simplemodal-container  {color:#999; background-color:#fff;}
#simplemodal-container a{color:#ddd;}

.modalMap:hover,.nonModalMap:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#mapCanvas {
    position:relative;
    width:480px;height:300px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myMap;
    $('.modalMap').click(function(){
        buildMap();
        $('#mapCanvas').modal(
            {onOpen:function(dialog){
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    dialog.data.hide();dialog.container.fadeIn('fast',function(){
                            dialog.data.slideDown('fast');
                    });
                });
            }

            ,onClose:function(dialog){
            dialog.data.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                dialog.container.hide('fast',function(){
                        dialog.overlay.slideUp('fast',function(){
                                $.modal.close();
                                });
                        });
                });
            }
        });
    });

/*  But without the modal the map displays correctly... */
    $('.nonModalMap').click(function(){
        buildMap();
    });
});

function buildMap() {
    var kpl = {
        Place: function (data, map) {

            var self = this;

            this.data = data;

            var coords = data.geo_coords.split(',');
            this.position = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);

            this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: this.position, 
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', function() { 
                if (self.data.url) {
                    window.location.href = self.data.url
                }
            });
        },
        MapManager: function (div, data) {
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(div, {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.818298, -1.573263),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: false,
                backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
                streetViewControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
            });
            saveCenter = this.map.center;

            this.places = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    this.places.push(new kpl.Place(data[i], this.map));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    myMap = new kpl.MapManager($('#mapCanvas').get(0), [{
        url: "mailto:info@????.com", 
        geo_coords: "53.818298, -1.573263",
        name: "Kensington Property LS6"
    }]);

}
```

/* plus the simplemodal library... */

I've recreated the code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/redApples/j23ue0n1/32/

Can anybody rescue my sanity...?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j23ue0n1/39/

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle - a definite improvement! Although it's still only on the second iteration that the map is fully rendered with the marker and correctly centered - plus the mapCanvas background remains stubbornly visible

Comment: I finally got this working by adding a "myMap.map.setCenter(mapCenter);" on dialogue open and a "$('#mapCanvas').css('background-color','transparent');" on dialogue close. Again, thanks for taking the time to look at this.
See: jsfiddle.net/redApples/j23ue0n1/44/